# What does the 「っち」　in ＠「見守りっち」 translate into?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does Verb in 「ます」form +「っち」　mean?

What does the 「っち」　in ＠「見守りっち」 translate into?

Comment: Please provide some context.

Answer (score 2):

From googling, "見守りっち" is the name of a product which monitors temperature for the purpose of warning if there is a danger of heatstroke.

So in this case I think we have:

見守り - "masu-stem" used as a noun.

っち - suffix sometimes used on names to form a nickname (あだ名{な})

There is a very famous product which uses a similar name. If you were a kid at the right time, you may have had one - commonly romanised as Tamagotchi (たまごっち).  Comparing the look of the two products, I think this may be a direct reference.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [たまごっち](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%94%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1) is a portmanteau of たまご and ウオッチ.  I imagine っち in 見守りっち could serve the same purpose...?

Comment: Quite possible - I didn't realise the っち there came from a portmanteau (and wouldn't have guessed ウオッチ!).  I thought it was just a cutesy suffix.